# Breeze manager.createEntity This key is already attached

Tags: local-storage, breeze

I have a SPA (hot towel template) and use window.localStore for keep data in browser. I used export/import from breeze 1.3.5, but later of use import entities function I need to create an other new entity and use again this line:

```
manager.createEntity('Project');
```

And the next error appears:

```
This key is already attached: Project:#Solution.Project.Models--1
```

The error only appears when I use import entities function to localStorage before call function `createEntity`.

Steps of test:

1. Open browser, create entities
2. Import entities to localStorage
3. Close browser
4. Open browser and load data from localStorage
5. Create a new entity and here appears error `This key is already attached: Project:#Solution.Project.Models--1`

If I didn't close the browser all work fine, but the error appeared when I had closed the browser and opened again, load data from localStorage and create a new entity.

Please, help me with this error.

Comment: I just tried this in DocCode sample with Northwind Project and it works fine. Perhaps this is because I'm using a version of Breeze that has not yet been released. If so ... well ... the fix is on the way :)

Comment: Thanks for your information, definitely in next version of breeze this error will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have alredy create the entity Project. Try to search in all the solution "createEntity" and see if there's another entity called Project.

Comment: No, maybe you need to review this link: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/creating-entities

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but there was a bug in Breeze related to Export/Import that was just fixed in v 1.3.5.  Can you try that and let us know if that was the issue?

Comment: The error appears when the key is an integer data type and identity or autogenerated (or auto increment) and the function `createEntity` fails after call function `importEntities` because `createEntity` try to assign the `id = -1` again, when `createEntity` must be assign new key `id = -2` for example.

Answer (score 0):

ddtere,

We were not able to reproduce the problem here.

Here's the snippet from our Hot Towel test solution:

```
return manager.executeQuery(query)
    .then(function (data) {
        var newPhysician0 = manager.createEntity('Physician');
        var bundle = manager.exportEntities();
        var em2 = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: manager.serviceName,
            metadataStore: manager.metadataStore
        });
        em2.importEntities(bundle);
        var newPhysician1 = manager.createEntity('Physician');
        var newPhysician2 = em2.createEntity('Physician');
        var newPhysician3 = manager.createEntity('Physician');
        var newPhysician4 = em2.createEntity('Physician');

        querySucceeded(data);
    })
    .fail(queryFailed);
```

Can you provide a solution reproducing the issue so we can investigate further? Please keep the solution to a minimum necessary to repro the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If I didn't close the browser all work fine, but the error appeared when I had closed the browser and opened again, load data from localStorage and create a new entity. (I edited my question and I had added steps of test).

Comment: Please make your test solution available so we can try to repro then. Thanks.